# Dynamically change icon variant in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have the following template which I'm trying to change dynamically when values in `data` has been changed:

```
<div class="vote-bar-content">
  <button class="vote-btn" @click="upvote(news)">
    <b-icon icon="chevron-up" 
    :variant="upvoteVariant(news)"></b-icon>
  </button>
  <span class="vote"> No. of vote goes here </span>
  <button class="vote-btn" @click="downvote(news)" >
    <b-icon icon="chevron-down"
    :variant="downvoteVariant(news)"></b-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to change both the `b-icon` variants into their respective value according to `upvoteVariant` and `downvoteVariant` when the user user clicks on the respective `vote-btn`. Below are both functions that are bound to the `b-icon` elements which are listed on Vue methods:

```
upvoteVariant(news) {
  if (this.votingList[news._id].upvoted) {
    return 'warning'
  }
  else {
    return ''
  }
},

downvoteVariant(news) {
  if (this.votingList[news._id].downvoted) {
    return 'primary'
  }
  else {
    return ''
  }
}
```

When the button is clicked and the method `upvote(news)` is called, changes on `this.votingList[news._id]` takes place and the value is altered as shown below:

```
async upvote(news) {
  axios.post(serverSide.findUserByID, {userID: this.user._id})
  .then((res) => {
    this.user.rep = res.data.user.rep
    if (this.votingList[news._id].upvoted == true) {
      alert('You have already voted!')
      return
    }
    else {
      axios.post(serverSide.castVote, {
        // function params
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.votingList[news._id].upvoted = true
        alert("Vote Casted")
        console.log("Voting List: ", this.votingList[news._id])
        this.upvoteVariant(news)
        return
      })
    }
  })
},
```

So why isn't `b-icon`'s variant changing even though the data has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `upvoted` and `downvoted` were not initially in the `news` object (they were inserted by `upvote()` and `downvote()`, respectively), Vue 2 [cannot detect addition/deletion of properties in objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

As a workaround, you could use [`this.$set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async upvote(news) {
      const item = this.votingList[news._id]
      if (item.upvoted || item.downvoted) {
        alert('You have already voted!')
        return
      }
      this.$set(item, 'upvoted', true) 
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/setting-array-sub-property-reactively-fki39?file=/App.vue)